# Grouping by specifying unique keys

Tags: r, tidyverse

In dplyr, I'm looking for way/s to group by unique keys(for the problem at hand, by unique row numbers). Given a dataframe such as below:

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(1:5, each = 2), B = rnorm(10, 3, 3), C= runif(10, 1.5, 4.5))
#>    A          B        C
#> 1  1 -4.6399372 1.622857
#> 2  1  0.9933197 4.256062
#> 3  2  4.1381981 3.522439
#> 4  2  4.6943698 4.260124
#> 5  3  5.7183797 3.877568
#> 6  3 -3.6183500 2.236473
#> 7  4 -2.5711393 4.373780
#> 8  4  5.9092908 2.125349
#> 9  5  6.1531930 4.472758
#> 10 5 -1.9750869 1.516432
```

I would like to get a row of `mean` of three rows(`df[4:6, ]`) which replaces those specified in the index with single row. Thus the result would produce only 8 rows in total after grouping and collapsing. Normally, I would work the way out in following manner:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(rownumber = c(1:3, rep(4, each=3), 7:10)) %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs = mean)
```

But, I find the code overtly explicit, in that each slice of index has to be provided.

There must be more efficient/succinct ways to achieve the same feat. Thanks to anyone to offer insights. And also, although tidyverse community seems to dodge the row naming convention, for now, I'd like to have a proper row numbering here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to `replace` those elements with a specific value so that we can avoid the `rep` and the later concatenation step

```
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = replace(row_number(), 4:6, 4)) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean)
```